# Python how to split string at "→" Char

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, split

What I'm doing is webscraping using selenium and python 3, I'm getting text from a data box and need to split it at "→" character, I'm lost on how to do that. The line I have is `whole_text.split("→")` and an example value for 'whole_text' is

"He let them in and locked the door, leaving the big, bad wolf outside trying to blow the brick house down. → Climax, One day, a big, bad wolf came along and blew down the straw house! → Rising Action,"

I think it has something to do with the encoding, when I pasted "→" into wing ide it told me to pick and encoding, I picked UTF-8 but I ran into a similar problem earlier with the same website where python ran an exception about encoding when I copy and pasted the "-" character in and it was slightly longer. How can I go about converting this value or even seeing what encoding the char is.

I should also mention for what I'm doing, something like split at any non ASCII character would also work

Edit: (more code)

```
def setmatch(self, soup):
    r_soup = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class' : 'rightanswer'})
    hole_text = r_soup.get_text()
    hole_text = hole_text[23:]
    #hole_text = self.make_unicode(hole_text)
    hole_text.split("→")
    for i in range(0, len(hole_text), 2):
        Op = hole_text[i]
        ans = hole_text[i+1]
    Op_ans = zip(op, ans)
    self.options_match = Op_ans
```

Comment: What have you tried? What was the result? Post your code. Python 3 uses Unicode for strings so there's no point in worrying about encodings. Encodings would be an issue if you loaded the string from a file with a specific encoding

Comment: `when I pasted` are you sure you pasted a single character instead of a combination that looks like an arrow in a specific editor or font? `webscraping` in that case the arrow is most likely an HTML escape sequence, not a single character. Or it may not be there at all - the web page may be using an arrow class from eg FontAwesome.  Have you tried typing the arrow character yourself?

Comment: `I copy and pasted the "-" character in and it was slightly longer.` that's because it wasn't the dash character, it was one of the [many other dash characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash). This has nothing to do with UTF8 - Python strings are UTF8 already

Comment: Use `View Source` in your browser to inspect the actual HTML and text. Selenium sees this HTML source and styles. You can find a list of arrow characters and their encodings in many sites like  [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_arrows.asp)

Comment: BTW I have no problem splitting what you posted. If I copy that string into a Python console and split, the array has 3 elements. That can happen if you copied the text from a browser - the arrow escape sequence would be replaced by the actual character, the same way `\n` is replaced by a newline in Python strings. You'll have to post actual code that reproduces the problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Basically im using beautiful soup to get the text, I coped the arrow from the show string in Wing IDE, I think pasting it to the text input on stack might convert it or my issue might be entirely different  Ill edit in more code right now

Comment: That's your actual issue though: what you see isn't the same as the HTML source.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That makes sense, do you have any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Python strings are **not** UTF-8. UTF-8 is an encoding. Python strings are unicode. And even the internal representation is not UTF-8 (see https://rushter.com/blog/python-strings-and-memory/).

Comment: @Matthias  in %90 of SO Python questions confuse Unicode for escape sequences. After writing `it's neither ASCII nor escape sequences` or `it's your console font` in comments several times a week, I'm afraid I started omitting details

Comment: @Matthias a common pattern is Python or R devs that started in a non-Unicode OS like Linux where they used escape sequences to avoid modifying LC_ALL wondering why their code behaves differently in Unicode OSs like Windows. Or US/Western European devs that have to process Cyrillic or Chinese text for the first time.

Comment: @milesfryett what does `hole_text` contain? Try printing it to the console or writing it to a file *with* `encoding=utf-8'` `utf-8` isn't the default for `open`.

Comment: It is working with default encoding but if  you are still facing an issue with encoding try to set the `encoding="ISO-8859-1" ` .  I tried with  `with open("test.txt","r",encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
    y=f.read().split("â\x86\x92")`  where `â\x86\x92` is a combination of utf-8 and numerical HTML encoding of the Unicode character for the symbol("→").

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem splitting what you posted. If I copy that string into a Python console and split, the array has 3 elements.

```
>>> whole_words="He let them in and locked the door, leaving the big, bad wolf outside trying to blow the brick house down. → Climax, One day, a big, bad wolf came along and blew down the straw house! → Rising Action,"
>>> arr=whole_text.split("→")
>>> len(arr)
3
>>> arr[2]
' Rising Action,'
```

Python 3 strings are Unicode. Almost all web sites use UTF8, so Unicode and UTF8 aren't a special case, they're the default. Unicode was always the default and only option in other languages like Java, JavaScript, all .NET languages like C#, F# and even in the ancient pre-.NET Visual Basic.

In web scraping, UTF8 is almost *never* the problem.

Most likely, what you try to split contains an HTML escape sequence like `&rarr;`. Like the `\n` escape sequence in Python strings, this will render as a newline on screen and even result in a newline if you copy the output. If you try to split the *source* though, there won't be any newline.

Another possibility is that the web page uses [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons/arrow-right?style=solid) or a similar font and CSS classes to render arrows instead of escape sequences, eg :

```
<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
```

You can find lists of HTML escape sequences in many places, eg [a list of arrow characters](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_arrows.asp). Just like arrow characters, there are [many different dashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) as well. That's why you can find longer or shorter dashes in documents and HTML pages.

You'll have to inspect the source of the web page that's causing you trouble to find out what the source looks like. Since you use Selenium, you'll have to inspect the actual string returned by `get_Text()` too.